# regex optional word match

Tags: regex

I'm trying to create a regex for extracting singers, lyricists. I was wondering how to make lyricists search optional.

Sample Multiline String:

```
Fireworks Singer: Katy Perry
Vogue Singers: Madonna, Karen Lyricist: Madonna
```

Regex: `/Singers?:(.\*)\s?Lyricists?:(.\*)/`

This matches the second line correctly and extracts `Singers(Madonna, Karen)` and `Lyricists(Madonna)`

But it does not work with the first line, when there are no Lyricists.

How do I make Lyricists search optional?

Answer (score 149, accepted):

You can enclose the part you want to match in a non-capturing group: `(?:)`. Then it can be treated as a single unit in the regex, and subsequently you can put a `?` after it to make it optional. Example:

```
/Singers?:(.*)\s?(?:Lyricists?:(.*))?/
```

Note that here the `\s?` is useless since `.*` will greedily eat all characters, and no backtracking will be necessary. This also means that the `(?:Lyricists?:(.*))` part will never be matched for the same reason. You can use the non-greedy version of `.*`, `.*?` along with the `$` to fix this:

```
/Singers?:(.*?)\s*(?:Lyricists?:(.*))?$/
```

Some extra whitespace ends up captured; this can be removed also, giving a final regex of:

```
/Singers?:\s*(.*?)\s*(?:Lyricists?:\s*(.*))?$/
```

Comment: How would this work with using the matched patterns (`$1`, `$2`...) would nested brackets also be referenced via a number?

Comment: @puk: I'm not sure I understand your question. `(?:)` is a non-capturing group, meaning anything they match can't be referenced via `$1`, etc. `()` is a capturing group, meaning anything they match is captured and available through `$1`, etc. If you have nested `(())` groups, the outermost one will be `$1`, and the inner one will be `$2`, etc. (this still follows the normal left-to-right rule; the opening `(` parentheses are in determine which group gets which number).

Comment: that kind of answers my question, I wanted to know about something like `(([a-z]{32})?):(([0-9]{32})?)` an optional username:id double. If I run that on the string `":"` will both `$1` and `$2` be empty? What about `"john:"`? Is there a `$3` and a `$4`?

Comment: @puk: Hmm, let's see. The best & fastest way would be to run that thru a regex tester (or write your own tests with your specific regex engine). But let me take a crack at it. You have four groups. For ':', groups 1 and 3 have a value of the empty string, since they match everything inside them (i.e. optional stuff). Groups 2 and 4 (the ones followed by `?`) are undefined/null/empty-string depending on the language/regex engine. You could simplify the regex to 2 groups: `([a-z]{32})?:([0-9]{32})?` or use non-capturing groups: `((?:[a-z]{32})?):((?:[0-9]{32})?)`.

Comment: re.compile(r'(.*)(?:SKIPPED?)(?:PASSED?)(?:FAILED?)')

Can i use above expression to optionally search for SKIPPED /PASSED/Failed.....and one of them has to be present

Answer (score 1):

Just to add to Cameron's solution. if the source string has multiple lines each containing both Singers and Lyricists, you'll probably need to add the 'm' multi-line modifier so that the '$' will match ends-of-lines. (You didn't say what language you are using - you may want to add the 'i' modifier as well.)