# Regex - optional value

Tags: regex

`preg_match_all('/<p class="row">(.+?)<\/span>(.+?)- <a href="(.+?)">(.+?)<\/a>(.+?)<font size="-1"> \((.+?)\)<\/font>(.+?)<\/p>/is', $HTML, $matches);`

I have the following regex, the problem is that only sometimes does the  section actually show up.  The regex I have requires the font to be there, how can I make it optional?

Not only mkae it optional, but pull a value if it exists

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5254804/regex-optional-word-match

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is working for me:

```
(?:<font size="-1">(.+?)<\/font>)?
```

Further example:

```
% perl -e '$x = "ab<font size=\"-1\">foo</font>"; print "$1 $2" if $x =~ /(ab)(?:<font size="-1">(.+?)<\/font>)?/'
ab foo

% perl -e '$x = "ab<font size=\"-1\">foo</fontXXXXXXX>"; print "$1 $2" if $x =~ /(ab)(?:<font size="-1">(.+?)<\/font>)?/'
ab
```

Comment: I don't want it to be non-capturing.  I want it to get what's in the font tag when it's available, but if the font tag doesn't exist that's ok.  I tried `'/<p class="row">(.+?)<\/span>(.+?)- <a href="(.+?)">(.+?)<\/a>(<font size="-1"> \((.+?)\)<\/font>)?(.+?)<\/p>/is'` and it doesn't pull what's between the font tags.

Comment: Perhaps your regex is failing to match on the space and the ( and ) within your font tag.  i.e. try relaxing your matching group to just be whatever's inside the font tag, and see if that yields a match.

Comment: Please can you explain ?

Answer (score 0):

You can make font optional like:

```
(<\/font>)?
```

Comment: I need to make it optional, and pull the value between those tags