# How to carry out optional leading word match in regex

Tags: regex

I'm quite new to the use of regex. I'm building a word parser and I need to replace line segments, which could show up as `AB` or `Line AB`, into `Line(AB)`. I have checked out [regex optional word match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5254804/regex-optional-word-match), but in my case the leading `Line` word is optional, when I use `(?:[Ll]ine)?\b([A-Z])([A-Z])` the engine just replaces the `AB` and it becomes `Line Line(AB)`.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could optionally match Line and capture AB in a group.

```
\b(?:[Ll]ine )?(AB)\b
```

Int he replacement use `Line`  followed by the capturing group `$1` or `\1` between parenthesis.

```
Line ($1)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/6sNIXy/1)

Or with multiple uppercase chars instead of AB only

```
\b(?:[Ll]ine )?([A-Z]+)\b
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/PpiWI9/1)

Comment: Thanks! It works this way. Could u perhaps explain why grouping AB together works but not when they’re separately grouped?

Comment: @JohnsonZhou You have to repeat the character class `[A-Z]` and there is a space after Line. You optionally match `Line ` so that it is not duplicated in the replacement and then you put it back.