# Regex to match value starting or not starting with a string

Tags: regex

Inspired by this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5254804/regex-optional-word-match), I'm using the following regex to match the total value `Total (EUR)?:\s*(.*?)\s*(?:Total?:\s*(.*))?$`.

```
Total (EUR)                     833.00
```

There may be cases where `(EUR)` part is missing, so I'd need something to catch the `Total` value  with or without the currency specified between parenthesis.

```
Total                         1 833.00
```

[Demo](http://regexr.com/66hig)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several issues here. First, your regex can look like

```cs
Total(?:\s*\(EUR\))?\s*(\d{1,3}(?: \d{3})*\.\d{2})
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/iUcPl5/3).

Note:

- Escape literal parentheses
- Match whitespace with `[ \t]*` /  `*` or `\s*`
- Put the whitespace in the optional part inside the optional group.

*Details*:

- `Total` - a literal string
- `(?:\s*\(EUR\))?` - **an optional non-capturing group**:

  - `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
  - `\(EUR\)` - `(EUR)` string
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `(\d{1,3}(?: \d{3})*\.\d{2})` - Group 1: one, two or three digits and then zero or more occurrences of space and three digits, then `.` and two digits. **Note** that this pattern might need further adjustment depending on the number formats you need to support*.

Answer (score 1):

Here you are the regex string:

```
Total (?:\s*\(EUR\))*\s*([\d\.\'\s]+?)\s*$
```

That matches all types of number, including spaces, dots and apostrophes!

Andrea

Comment: @shAkur I just updated the regex string...now it won't match the spaces!

Answer (score 1):

If there can be other currencies or non digits in between, you can match any char other than a digit in between using `\D*` until the first occurrence of the digits.

```
Total\s\D*(\d{1,3}(?:[ ,]\d{3})*(?:\.\d{2})?)\b
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/gmwYLZ/1/)